# how to get the file name from the string in python

Tags: python

I have a string like this:

```
out = """Tue Nov  7  07:20:56.948 UTC
total 1224
    11 -rw------- 1    243 Nov  7 06:50 .bash_history
    12 -rw-r--r-- 1 364236 Nov  5 12:24 bh_cardmgr_1899.by.11.20171105-122102.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz
    15 -rw-r--r-- 1  42082 Nov  5 13:03 bh_cardmgr_1900.by.11.20171105-130244.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt
    14 -rw-r--r-- 1 365799 Nov  5 13:03 bh_cardmgr_1900.by.11.20171105-130244.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz
    16 -rw-r--r-- 1 366337 Nov  7 04:58 bh_cardmgr_1887.by.11.20171107-045835.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz
131074 drwxr-xr-x 4   4096 Nov  7 05:27 cisco_support
131073 drwxr-xr-x 2   4096 Nov  5 09:22 tftpboot
    13 -rw-r--r-- 1  42082 Nov  5 12:24 bh_cardmgr_1899.by.11.20171105-122102.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt
131077 drwxr-xr-x 2   4096 Nov  5 09:31 dumper
    17 -rw-r--r-- 1  42082 Nov  7 04:58 bh_cardmgr_1887.by.11.20171107-045835.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt
"""
```

I just want to get the file names from this string and create a list of those filenames. How do I get an output like this?

```
list = [bh_cardmgr_1899.by.11.20171105-122102.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz, bh_cardmgr_1900.by.11.20171105-130244.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt, bh_cardmgr_1900.by.11.20171105-130244.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz]
```

Comment: You only want filenames starts with `bh_*` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your requirement, regex is the simple way to resolve.
Regex is very powerful, you can learn it by google it!

```python
import re

out = """Tue Nov  7  07:20:56.948 UTC
total 1224
    11 -rw------- 1    243 Nov  7 06:50 .bash_history
    12 -rw-r--r-- 1 364236 Nov  5 12:24 bh_cardmgr_1899.by.11.20171105-122102.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz
    15 -rw-r--r-- 1  42082 Nov  5 13:03 bh_cardmgr_1900.by.11.20171105-130244.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt
    14 -rw-r--r-- 1 365799 Nov  5 13:03 bh_cardmgr_1900.by.11.20171105-130244.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz
    16 -rw-r--r-- 1 366337 Nov  7 04:58 bh_cardmgr_1887.by.11.20171107-045835.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz
131074 drwxr-xr-x 4   4096 Nov  7 05:27 cisco_support
131073 drwxr-xr-x 2   4096 Nov  5 09:22 tftpboot
    13 -rw-r--r-- 1  42082 Nov  5 12:24 bh_cardmgr_1899.by.11.20171105-122102.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt
131077 drwxr-xr-x 2   4096 Nov  5 09:31 dumper
    17 -rw-r--r-- 1  42082 Nov  7 04:58 bh_cardmgr_1887.by.11.20171107-045835.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt
"""

def Func(data):
    output = list()

    data_lines = data.split('\n')
    p = re.compile(r'\s*\d+ -[-rwx]+ \d+ \s*\d+ \w{3}\s*\d+ \d{2}:\d{2} (.*)')

    for x in data_lines:
        result = p.match(x)
        if result:
            output.append(result.groups(1)[0])

    return output

print(Func(out))
```

the result will be:

```python
['.bash_history', 
'bh_cardmgr_1899.by.11.20171105-122102.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz', 
'bh_cardmgr_1900.by.11.20171105-130244.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt', 
'bh_cardmgr_1900.by.11.20171105-130244.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz', 
'bh_cardmgr_1887.by.11.20171107-045835.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz', 
'bh_cardmgr_1899.by.11.20171105-122102.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt', 
'bh_cardmgr_1887.by.11.20171107-045835.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt']
```

Comment: For generality, the permissions field should include [-rwxsStT]

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. Can i get the remaining values like "cisco support","tftp boot", "dumper"?

Comment: @sruthikadukuntla you can change `-[-rwx]+` to `[-drwx]+` or @rain city said, `[-drwxsStT]+`

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the file is consistent, you can use:

```
file_list = []

for line in out.split('\n'):
    if len(line.split()) == 8:
        file_list.append(line.split()[7])
```

Which gives:

```
['.bash_history',
 'bh_cardmgr_1899.by.11.20171105-122102.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz',
 'bh_cardmgr_1900.by.11.20171105-130244.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt',
 'bh_cardmgr_1900.by.11.20171105-130244.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz',
 'bh_cardmgr_1887.by.11.20171107-045835.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz',
 'cisco_support',
 'tftpboot',
 'bh_cardmgr_1899.by.11.20171105-122102.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt',
 'dumper',
 'bh_cardmgr_1887.by.11.20171107-045835.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Positive Lookbehind (?<=\d{2}:\d{2}\s)`

```
import re
pattern=r'(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}\s)\w.+'

print(re.findall(pattern,out))
```

output:

```
['bh_cardmgr_1899.by.11.20171105-122102.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz', 'bh_cardmgr_1900.by.11.20171105-130244.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt', 'bh_cardmgr_1900.by.11.20171105-130244.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz', 'bh_cardmgr_1887.by.11.20171107-045835.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.gz', 'cisco_support', 'tftpboot', 'bh_cardmgr_1899.by.11.20171105-122102.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt', 'dumper', 'bh_cardmgr_1887.by.11.20171107-045835.sysadmin-vm.ec937.core.txt']
```